# Delete Azure-DevOps Account

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have two accounts on Azure-DevOps and I want to delete one of them because I don't need two.

I don't have any subscriptions, projects or organization on that account.

I can't find anything useful on google or bing about deleting an entire account.

Edit: I don't just want to delete an organization but an entrie profile.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't have any subscriptions, projects or organization on that account, why not just delete the account from browser cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't just want to delete an organization but an entrie profile

If you mean you want to delete the entrie profile, even if the account do not have any subscriptions, projects or organization on that account, I am afraid you could not delete the entrie profile after we delete the user in the organization.

That because if an account is removed, the profile is just not available anymore. In other words, Microsoft then keeps these orphaned profile data in the back, the user and anybody else using Azure DevOps services or API, this profile does just not exist anymore.

I have [similar thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/gdpr-deleting-azure-devops-user-profile/1456025?from=email&viewtype=all#T-ND1464629) about this question, you could refer this thread for some more details:

> The GDPR delete service is responsible for ensuring that when an
> identity is deleted from the AAD/MSA systems, any and all
> corresponding EUII (End User Identifiable Information) is deleted
> and/or obscured from our systems within 30 days.
>
> We have tested it using Postman API testing tool with valid credential
> and observed that while accessing the resource which is not available
> in the organization, we are getting 403 forbidden error, means our
> credentials are getting validated but we are not able to see that
> requested resource because that resource is no more available in that
> organization and it has been deleted. Authentication is happening
> successfully but we are not able to see that requested resource due to
> its unavailability.